# Help with a proof about heat equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, heat-equation

The question is

> Suppose $U=\Omega \times (0,T)$ where $\Omega \subseteq \Bbb{R}^n$ is a bounded domain. Let $u\in C_1^2(U)\bigcap C(\bar U)$ satisfy $u_t \le\Delta u + cu$ in $U$ where $c \le 0$ is a constant. If $u \ge 0$, show that $u$ contains maximum on the parabolic boundary of $U$. Give a counter example if the condition $u \ge 0$ is not satisfied.

I once solved this question but today when I looked at my solution again, I got a problem. The following is a scan of my solution. Zoom it in you can see it clearly.

**The inequality underlined blue** "$\frac{\partial }{{\partial t}}u - \Delta u - 2n\varepsilon  < c(u + \varepsilon |x{|^2})$" **is my problem**, why this inequity holds?

It is only given that $\frac{\partial }{{\partial t}}u - \Delta u \le cu$. In order for the inequality to hold, $ - 2n\varepsilon  < c\varepsilon |x{|^2}$ must hold, thus $ - 2n < c|x{|^2}$. But we don't have any information about $x$ except for it is bounded.

Thank you!

[image]

Comment: I feel like I am missing something obvious.  You ask, why is $-2n < |x|^2$.  Isn't it because the left hand side is negative, and the right hand side is non-negative?

Comment: @StephenMontgomery-Smith : you forgot the $c$, that is negative, hence both sides are negative

Comment: Duh!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: As @Tryss suggested maybe we need to construct $\epsilon$ in a different way. There might be mistake in my solution, but since my professor thought it is right, I think it is very close.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can adapt your proof by using

$$V_{\epsilon}(x,t) =  u(x,t) + \epsilon \left( |x|^2 -\sup_{x\in\Omega} |x|^2 \right)  $$

Then you have

$$\Delta \left( |x|^2 -\sup_{x\in\Omega} |x|^2 \right) = -2n < 0 \leq c\left( |x|^2 -\sup_{x\in\Omega} |x|^2 \right) $$

Comment: Yes, this one works! Thank you so much!